# Pinned apps on taskbar are missing until repinning or restarting Explorer

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, dism, pinning

My Dell Inspiron 5558 has been updated to Windows 10 Creators Update. Few days after updating, pinned apps on the taskbar disappeared. I have been trying fixing this weird behavior by doing some workarounds:

- Repinning one of the apps. All the pinned apps appear, but after the laptop restarts, they are gone again.
- Restarting Explorer. Same behavior as above.
- Using `sfc /scannow` in an elevated Command Prompt. It completes successfully, but it does not find any violations.
- "Upgrading" Windows using Media Creation Tool. It looks like the problem has been fixed, but after some system reboots, the problem returns.

---

I have also tried the following fix. Things have become interesting.

I download installation ISO file from Microsoft website (not via Media Creation Tool), mount it and then use `dism` in an elevated command prompt:

```
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:wim:D:\sources\install.wim:1 /LimitAccess
```

where `D:` is the virtual drive created after mounting the ISO.

- First try: The command does not finish. It shows the error code `0x800f081f` with a message `The source files could not be found.` I check the logs and find that `Dism` stops at `Microsoft-Windows-TestRoot-and-FlightSigning-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.15063.0` which is a problematic package. I have removed that package, like this [post](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/643994/windows-package-file-bad-digital-signature/#entry4224265) instructs.
- Second try: The command finishes successfully. But after restarting Windows, pinned apps still do not show on the taskbar.

---

Before removing that package, I tried running the following `Dism` commands, and they also nearly finish with error `0x800f081f`:

```
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:wim:D:\sources\install.wim:1
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:esd:D:\sources\install.esd:1
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:esd:D:\sources\install.esd:1 /LimitAccess
```

---

A very interesting thing is that the problem does not appear when I get into Safe Mode. I try removing video drivers, then reboot and return to normal mode to have those drivers downloaded and installed automatically from Windows Update. But when I return to normal mode, the problem is still there.

---

UPDATE: I have tried uninstalling all drivers and apps that I have downloaded from Dell Support, and then let Windows Update install drivers for the laptop. The problem is gone, but only when I turn off the laptop completely and then turn on again. The problem still exists when I just perform a restart command.

---

Is there a permanent fix to this problem? Or, do I have to wait for a new update?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause of this problem. It is Ransomware Protection module of BitDefender 2017.

When I turn on *Protection at boot*, BitDefender's service makes the hard disk too busy on reboot, leading to the temporary disappearance of pinned apps on the taskbar. [The problem has been known for some time.](https://forum.bitdefender.com/index.php?/topic/74151-taskbars-pinned-icons-disappear-if-desktop-directory-is-protected-by-anti-ransomware/)

After updating BitDefender, the problem is now gone.